# Record Videos While Running Selenium Tests In Parallel

Tags: c#, selenium

I have searched everywhere for this, but came up with nothing. Is there a way to record a video of each Selenium tests that get run in parallel? The below is an open source project, but I dont believe this supports video with parallel test execution

https://github.com/aimmac23/selenium-video-node

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Zalenium:

https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/

They provide you a docker based implementation of the selenium grid.
Tests are recorded in isolation and can be viewed from a central dashboard that reports all tests, if they passed or failed and also their video recording and browser/test logs.